# Pokemon Go transfer issue

Tags: pokemon-go

Before, when I transferred a Pokemon to the professor, I returned to the same Pokemon in the A-Z function; now I am returned to the beginning.

This means scrolling down after each transfer, which is a time consuming matter.

What happened? I tried resetting the game and the phone but that did not change it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

That is a bug introduced in version 0.87.X, acknowledged via [Niantic's Twitter](https://twitter.com/niantichelp/status/944099154417954816).  It is fixed in version 0.89.X.